# How to get a new row from datatable for every click event for window from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable

i am having five rows in datatable i should get each row for every click event from datatable in windowform C# ?? I am using following code it works for only first row i.e getting only first record for every click event but i need each new row for every click event

```
        private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Select top " + que + " * from Samplebox", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sdr.SelectCommand = cmd3;
        sdr.Fill(ds, "Samplebox");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables["Samplebox"];
        int i=+0;

        if (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 )
        {
            i++;
            label3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BoxIDPK"].ToString();
            label4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][Box Name""].ToString();
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BoxType"]) == 0)
            {
                radioButton1.Visible = true;
                radioButton2.Visible = true;
                radioButton3.Visible = false;
                radioButton4.Visible = false;
                label7.Visible = false;
                label8.Visible = false;
                label5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Option1"].ToString();
                label6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Option2"].ToString();
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BoxType"]) == 1)
            {
                radioButton1.Visible = true;
                radioButton2.Visible = true;
                radioButton3.Visible = true;
                radioButton4.Visible = true;
            }

        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Calling con.Close() will prevent it from being opened again.  Make a new connection object inside the method.

Comment: tried your comment but not working -@Loathing

Comment: take away the i=+0. put it somewhere its only called once.